# Rename chapters to papers

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, cross-referencing, memoir, cleveref

The `\appendix` macro renames 'Chapter' to 'Appendix' and changes the numbering from Arabic to letters. I am trying to create a similar macro `\paper` that renames 'Chapter' to 'Paper' and changes the numbering to Roman numerals.

In that at least I have succeeded, but if I try to to click on a hyperlink to one of the paper-chapters, I am directed to a regular chapter. Moreover, if I make a cross reference with `\Cref` from the `cleveref` package, it gets the numeral right, but still prints 'Chapter'. How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\paper}
{
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \def \@chapapp{Paper}
    \def \thechapter{\@Roman\c@chapter}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents  % Hyperlink to 'First Paper' not working

    \chapter{First Chapter}
    \label{sec:chapter}

    \Cref{sec:chapter} % Correctly prints 'Chapter'
    \Cref{sec:paper}   % Incorrectly prints 'Chapter'

    \paper

    \chapter{First Paper}
    \label{sec:paper}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `cleveref` still stores this as `chapter` counter, regardless how the `chapter` is named

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redefining `\@chapapp` to `Paper` does not force `cleveref` to use `Paper` as cross-reference name -- it will use the counter information stored with the label, this is `chapter` and grabs the `\crefname` etc. stored for chapter.

Here is a way with a new counter `paper` that is increased with `\refstepcounter` at the end of the `\chapter` command with `\memendofchapterhook`  -- now `cleveref` is informed that `paper` instead of `chapter` is used.

The hyper anchor information stored in `\theHchapter` has to be modified as well.

Another possibility: Define the `paper` counter and say `\label[paper]{sec:paper}` locally.

Either way: `\crefname{paper}{paper}{papers}` etc. are necessary to provide the correct cross-referencing names.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{paper}


\newcommand{\paper}
{%
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\theHchapter}{papter.\arabic{chapter}}%
  \def\@chapapp{Paper}
  \let\c@paper\c@chapter
  \def\thechapter{\@Roman\c@chapter}
  \let\thepaper\thechapter
  \renewcommand{\memendofchapterhook}{%
    \addtocounter{paper}{-1}%
    \refstepcounter{paper}%
  }% 
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{paper}{paper}{papers}
\Crefname{paper}{Paper}{Papers}    


\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents  % Hyperlink to 'First Paper' not working

    \chapter{First Chapter}
    \label{sec:chapter}

    \Cref{sec:chapter} % Correctly prints 'Chapter'
    \Cref{sec:paper}   % Incorrectly prints 'Chapter'

    \paper

    \chapter{First Paper}
    \label{sec:paper}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Smart solution! +1

Answer (score 3):

You have to redefine `\theHchapter` to make unique numbers for `hyperref` targets. But to make `\paper` behave like `\appendix` including the naming of `\section` inside a paper also as "paper" (like a `\section` inside an appendix is also called `appendix`). Here I've copied the *appendix code* of `cleveref` and changed it for `paper` instead of `appendix`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\paper}
{
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \def \@chapapp{Paper}
    \def \thechapter{\@Roman\c@chapter}
    \def \theHchapter{paper-\@Roman\c@chapter}
    \def\H@refstepcounter##1{%
      \cref@old@H@refstepcounter{##1}%
      \cref@constructprefix{##1}{\cref@result}%
      \ifx\cref@result\@empty%
        \def\cref@result{2147483647}%
      \else%
        \edef\cref@result{2147483647,\cref@result}%
      \fi%
      \def\@tempa{##1}%
      \def\@tempb{chapter}%
      \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
        \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{%
          [paper][\arabic{##1}][\cref@result]%
          \csname p@##1\endcsname\csname the##1\endcsname}%
      \else%
        \def\@tempa{##1}%
        \def\@tempb{section}%
        \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
          \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{%
            [subpaper][\arabic{##1}][\cref@result]%
            \csname p@##1\endcsname\csname the##1\endcsname}%
        \else%
          \def\@tempa{##1}%
          \def\@tempb{subsection}%
          \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
            \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{%
              [subsubpaper][\arabic{##1}][\cref@result]%
              \csname p@##1\endcsname\csname the##1\endcsname}%
          \else%
            \def\@tempa{##1}%
            \def\@tempb{subsubsection}%
            \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
              \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{%
                [subsubsubpaper][\arabic{##1}][\cref@result]%
                \csname p@##1\endcsname\csname the##1\endcsname}%
            \else%
              \@ifundefined{cref@##1@alias}%
                {\def\@tempa{##1}}%
                {\def\@tempa{\csname cref@##1@alias\endcsname}}%
              \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{%
                [\@tempa][\arabic{##1}][\cref@result]%
                \csname p@##1\endcsname\csname the##1\endcsname}%
            \fi%
          \fi%
        \fi%
      \fi%  
    }%
}%
\AtBeginDocument{\Crefname@preamble{paper}{Paper}{Papers}}
  \Crefname{paper}{Paper}{Papers}%
  \Crefname{subpaper}{Paper}{Papers}%
  \Crefname{subsubpaper}{Paper}{Papers}%
  \Crefname{subsubsubpaper}{Paper}{Papers}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents  % Hyperlink to 'First Paper' not working

    \chapter{First Chapter}
    \label{sec:chapter}

    \Cref{sec:chapter} % Correctly prints 'Chapter'
    \Cref{sec:paper}   % Incorrectly prints 'Chapter'

    \Cref{sec:papersec}

    \paper
    \chapter{First Paper}
    \label{sec:paper}

    \section{First Paper section}
    \label{sec:papersec}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can change the names `subpaper`, `subsubpaper` etc. if you don't want to name a `\section`, `\subsection` etc. `paper` but, e.g., `papersection`.